# Convert javascript for loop into jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just started learning jQuery, this is my first project; I have classic JavaScript function that I need to convert to jQuery. Could any jQuery expert please help me?

Thank you in advance.

```
for (var i = 0; (l_link = document.getElementsByTagName("link")[i]); i++) {
  if (l_link.getAttribute("rel")) {
    if (l_link.getAttribute("rel").indexOf("style") != -1 && l_link.getAttribute("title")) {
      l_link.disabled = true;
      if (l_link.getAttribute("title") == theme_id) {
        l_link.disabled = false;
        applied = false;
        activetheme = v_css;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It would be nice to see your best try. Otherwise it's like *"Please, do it for me!"* Don't you think?

Comment: "*which [I] need to convert to [jQuery]*" - why?

Comment: Guys... i am learner thats why i asked such basic question... because of your down votes i can not ask any further questions..could you please revert your down vote... so that i can learn some basic stuff here... i am just learner here... please guys... thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('link').each(function(i, link) {
    link = $(link);
    if (link.attr('rel') && link.attr('rel').indexOf("style") != -1 && link.attr('title')) {
        if (link.attr('title') == theme_id) {
            link.attr('disabled', false);
            applied = false;
            activetheme = v_css;
        } else {
            link.attr('disabled', true);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It would look like this in JQuery.

```
$('link').each(function(i, l_link) {   
             if (l_link.attr('rel') && l_link.attr('rel').indexOf("style") != -1 && l_link.attr('title')) {  
        if (l_link.attr('title') == theme_id) {  
            l_link.attr('disabled', false);  
            applied = false;  
            activetheme = v_css;    
        } else {  
            l_link.attr('disabled', true);  
        }  
    }  
});
```